# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) Symfony PHP VERSION WAMP Windows

Tags: php, windows, wamp, symfony4

I have some syntax errors from symfony vendor when i'm trying to composer install my project.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) vendor\psr\log\src\LoggerInterface.php on line 30
```

With several search, I saw the problem is from PHP version (have to be > 7.1), but actually my version is 7.4.9, this is a local machine, i'm working with WAMP on Windows. Symfony 4.4 version. Already tried to delete vendor, .lock...

Here the php version from phpinfo()
[image: PHP version from phpinfo()]

Here php version from wamp
[image: PHP VERSION from wamp]

Here php version from CLI php-v  [image: php version from php v]

Here my composer.json

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",    
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.10@dev",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^4.2",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/messenger": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
},
"require-dev": {
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.4.9"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.4.*"
    }
}
}
```

Have some idea ?

Comment: You seemingly have [latest version installed](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/log), which uses PHP/8 syntax (you can check that with e.g. `composer info psr/log`). Either it's ignoring your `"platform"` settings for some reason, of you made changes but didn't update. Do you have a `composer.lock` file coming from the repository? Does `composer update` change something?

Comment: How does  `vendor\psr\log\src\LoggerInterface.php on line 30` look like, it is not accepting several parameters obviously, so there is a version issue with either the package or php.

Comment: Composer update would be helpful

Answer (score 24):

I added this in the composer.json and it worked.

```
"config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.21"
         }
   }
```

The run. `composer update`

This downgraded psr/log to a lower version from 2.0 and resolved my issue.

Comment: It's worth noting that the settings on the question already include a similar `platform` settings. It's possible that the OP didn't refresh with `composer update` or they had another issue.

Comment: Thx that saved my day. But note that you may have to re-install your libs (yust delete composer.lock and composer/installed.json and run `composer update`) to make this taking affect

Answer (score 20):

I got the solution.

uninstall composer using following command

```
sudo apt remove composer

sudo apt autoremove
```

switch to compatible php you are looking for using following command (if multiple php versions are running on your system)

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

then install composer using older method given on below link

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: which version works for php7.4

Answer (score 10):

This character '|' is used only in php version >= 8.0
You can update the php version

That worked for me :)

References: https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#union-types

Comment: This was it! I globally had PHP 7.4 (used by phpunit), but running in IntelliJ used the PHP 8.1 runner.

Answer (score 2):

If the other solutions not does works, u can try this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the vendor folder, delete the composer.lock file, then run composer install. that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error when I upgrade ubuntu version from 20 to 22. I was using php 7.4 version. I tried to find the solution on google and mostly was saying to upgrade php version to 8. I updated to php 8 version but then again composer start throwing errors in Laravel project. Nothing helpful. So I uninstall php 8 and then reinstall composer and php 7.4. Everything start working fine. So in my conclusion. We can try these steps:

1. Reinstall Php version
2. Reinstall composer if you are using composer.
3. Restart your apache or nginx server

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by using the wrong actual PHP version with the PHP-version stated in composer.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still relevant as I got the same issue today. Apparently v4.5.0 of Cocur/Slugify declares PHP 7.1 compatibility but that is not true; so you should force a lower version if you're still running on PHP 7.4.
See https://github.com/cocur/slugify/issues/332 for details and possible workarounds.